# Shouldn't my rotors turned easily when the calipers are off

Tags: brakes

My driver's front wheel is getting hot I was going to replace the calipers I've already replaced the brake hose but there seems to be something rubbing when I turn the rotor. I have the calipers off shouldn't my rotor turn freely

Comment: Does the opposite side turn easier?

Comment: Is there a rubbing sound or just resistance to turning? If it makes a noise, check the backing plate (the metal disk to the inside of the rotor) If you dent or bend it it rubs on the rotor. And to amplify, do both sides do this or just the drivers side?

Comment: What car is it (make/model/year)? If it's front wheel drive, have you checked that it's in neutral?

Answer (score 1):

As you don’t tell us the make, model or year then if it is front wheel drive - no, the rotors don’t spin freely as they are connected to the driveshafts and final-drive / gearbox.

But if it is a rwd and not 4x4 then yes they should spin.

Comment: Even if it's rear-wheel-drive the front hub has *some* resistance to turning.  A car wheel won't spin like the front wheel on a bicycle. It shouldn't be hard to turn, but it won't go on like a free spinning disk.

Comment: @TimNevins there is a massive difference between the bearings on a bicycle wheel and the ones used on cars - when I used the term freely I did not imply perpetual motion...